# RabbitMQ consumer does not listen to UN-ACKED messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

My consumer listen to a queue. Auto Ack = false.
- If I ACK message will be removed from the queue.
- And if I did not ACK, RabbitMQ will put the message to queue as expected. 
My problem is my consumer not CONTINUE TO LISTEN TO THOSE UN-ACKED messages. To verify that, if I put a new message, consumer picked it up.

Following is my code block. Any solution ?

```
while (true) {
        try {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
            String response = sendEndpoint(message);
            if (!response.equals(ERROR_CODE)) {
                channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
            } 
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try basic.reject?
As stated [in this blog entry](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/08/03/well-ill-let-you-go-basicreject-in-rabbitmq/), basic.reject will deliver it to the same queue and *"RabbitMQ doesn't take care to stop the same consumer getting the message again"*. So this should work for you.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you also might be interested in the dead letter feature. See [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for more information.